# How to remove dead space at the start of a bar chart in ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm looking to start right at the intercept with a bar chart and not have the wasted space before and below the intercept see the pic below.

The code I use to create the plot is:

```
df<-structure(list(Date = structure(c(2006, 2006.08333333333, 2006.16666666667, 
2006.25, 2006.33333333333, 2006.41666666667, 2006.5, 2006.58333333333, 
2006.66666666667, 2006.75, 2006.83333333333, 2006.91666666667, 
2007, 2007.08333333333, 2007.16666666667, 2007.25, 2007.33333333333, 
2007.41666666667, 2007.5, 2007.58333333333, 2007.66666666667, 
2007.75, 2007.83333333333, 2007.91666666667, 2008, 2008.08333333333, 
2008.16666666667, 2008.25, 2008.33333333333, 2008.41666666667, 
2008.5, 2008.58333333333, 2008.66666666667, 2008.75, 2008.83333333333, 
2008.91666666667, 2009, 2009.08333333333, 2009.16666666667, 2009.25, 
2009.33333333333, 2009.41666666667, 2009.5, 2009.58333333333, 
2009.66666666667, 2009.75, 2009.83333333333, 2009.91666666667, 
2010, 2010.08333333333, 2010.16666666667, 2010.25, 2010.33333333333, 
2010.41666666667, 2010.5, 2010.58333333333, 2010.66666666667, 
2010.75, 2010.83333333333, 2010.91666666667, 2011, 2011.08333333333, 
2011.16666666667, 2011.25, 2011.33333333333, 2011.41666666667, 
2011.5, 2011.58333333333, 2011.66666666667, 2011.75, 2011.83333333333, 
2011.91666666667, 2012, 2012.08333333333, 2012.16666666667, 2012.25, 
2012.33333333333, 2012.41666666667, 2012.5, 2012.58333333333, 
2012.66666666667, 2012.75, 2012.83333333333, 2012.91666666667, 
2013, 2013.08333333333, 2013.16666666667, 2013.25, 2013.33333333333, 
2013.41666666667, 2013.5, 2013.58333333333, 2013.66666666667, 
2013.75, 2013.83333333333, 2013.91666666667, 2014, 2014.08333333333, 
2014.16666666667, 2014.25, 2014.33333333333, 2014.41666666667, 
2014.5, 2014.58333333333, 2014.66666666667, 2014.75, 2014.83333333333, 
2014.91666666667, 2015, 2015.08333333333, 2015.16666666667, 2015.25, 
2015.33333333333, 2015.41666666667, 2015.5, 2015.58333333333, 
2015.66666666667, 2015.75, 2015.83333333333, 2015.91666666667, 
2016, 2016.08333333333, 2016.16666666667, 2016.25, 2016.33333333333, 
2016.41666666667, 2016.5, 2016.58333333333, 2016.66666666667, 
2016.75, 2016.83333333333, 2016.91666666667), class = "yearmon"), 
Y = c(0.0234783079450418, 0.224283779010341, 0.304039660720104, 
0.0610159090909091, 0.126916045536005, 0.151936026936027, 
0.222357988487021, 0.0897686542847833, 0.206579685746352, 
0.159997148908439, 0.194851290684624, 0.113758553274682, 
0.0722276528728142, 0.044338474025974, 0.200689692625176, 
0.302605920314254, 0.114596909959813, 0.0418490460157127, 
0.117240957966764, 0.0101247691973498, 0.137941919191919, 
0.149098512001738, 0.0933606902356902, 0.0361783154121864, 
0.113565086347344, 0.3029758794845, 0.353464076246334, 0.0784336419753086, 
0.0555250081459759, 0.0462471941638608, 0.164506506708759, 
0.446081985832758, 0.492881184175417, 0.164987855951855, 
0.12409200434977, 0.0374809779092038, 0.124755738169372, 
0.335018987178961, 0.227868704963499, 0.332334945030344, 
0.536188710392201, 0.255668027246671, 0.115761563554464, 
0.177167934093594, 0.164055578537428, 0.410618908218174, 
0.18670843090666, 0.0416980454077924, 0.0349195476113268, 
0.0366552169116827, 0.0811660206341392, 0.415836859988055, 
0.34071565198206, 0.0832490177574156, 0.321362468777135, 
0.488714360141981, 0.322350269113745, 0.251844581650896, 
0.19548612937705, 0.0376331975864431, 0.0440948717547222, 
0.363194190993752, 0.231690853646315, 0.131117360719224, 
0.45918340593851, 0.244516203285963, 0.072024706056286, 0.4211592669462, 
0.610101092821591, 0.419153187281342, 0.390813383197299, 
0.070886200790227, 0.0456797722483606, 0.0268271400291992, 
0.0216769781873034, 0.107849025013876, 0.294892098874362, 
0.108428534381569, 0.0379059555856125, 0.0427942415748888, 
0.0939487620451505, 0.0597480413834521, 0.0254660358275256, 
0.0311610673152602, 0.0330340844954633, 0.0414951594720611, 
0.0734924182400819, 0.399113335210493, 0.303025595104283, 
0.145348201763018, 0.211241883145092, 0.108154356256884, 
0.0157026221952164, 0.0969269305962854, 0.0281648078002245, 
0.0638060375257956, 0.0644470579450418, 0.499437567640693, 
0.292981155642446, 0.0703470468574635, 0.31911144373846, 
0.302404671717172, 0.692114389866406, 0.791766624579125, 
0.670735585016835, 0.420315283208428, 0.130145202020202, 
0.0592460220484414, 0.0301157067991745, 0.032127901034151, 
0.0319704097425872, 0.206240495230079, 0.379507949114804, 
0.323031320145903, 0.399382161670468, 0.247598973607038, 
0.161189464085297, 0.396057754969045, 0.0984525462962963, 
0.0323741107309656, 0.0316956867057673, 0.0432035883257866, 
0.0200122189638319, 0.0930482417929293, 0.441512809547084, 
0.221885907687991, 0.14996700438525, 0.0223509245682633, 
0.0586762408810325, 0.120861704409688, 0.116719375, 0.0760695126669925
)), .Names = c("Date", "Y"), row.names = c(NA, -132L), class = "data.frame")


barLF<- ggplot(df,  aes(x=as.Date(Date), y=Y)) #zoo object doesn't work with scales and has to be converted to a data object. 
barLF<-barLF+ geom_bar(stat="identity")
barLF<-barLF+scale_x_date( labels=date_format("%Y-%b"), breaks = date_breaks("6 months"), minor_breaks = date_breaks("3 months"))
barLF+scale_y_continuous(labels=percent, limits=c(0, 1)
```

[image]

Comment: Add `expand = c(0, 0)` inside your scale calls. See `?scale_x_date` or `?scale_y_continuous` for details.

Comment: This scale_y_continuous(labels=percent,expand = c(0, 0), limits=c(0, 1)) works for the y axis. But I can not get scale_x_date to work.

Comment: The code is not reproducible: missing closing parenthesis, missing library calls, error message when trying to convert `Date` to class `"Date".

Comment: Have you tried scale_x_datetime ?